# Wordpress ecommerce email

Tags: wordpress, email, e-commerce, wordpress-ecommerce

I have to deliver a WordPress eCommerce website but what if I give the role of editor to my client will he still get emails about the orders received on the website? *Actually this is my first eCommerce website*

Comment: Can you mention which WordPress version, which eCommerce plugin you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The e-commerce email (the address that receives the order notification) should have it's Name and password, it is sure that he can receive the received order notification from the email if you provide him with the credentials of this email address.  If he could access the website on the backend he could also access the orders.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write the email of the client in the Settings section of the WordPress. Your client will still get emails.

Answer (score -1):

He can even get the emails without getting the complete access to the wordpress. This is how I am doing it for my client at [maheenandco](https://maheenandco.com/). You just need to put his email address. You can use multiple emails. You will find the option in woo commerce settings.